# Check if part of the string exists in different dataframe and get this part only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My DF_1 looks like below:

```
id  x
1   eu continent hamburg
2   asia singapore
3   austrlia hedland
```

I have a second DF_2 that looks like below:

```
name
germany hamburg
singapore china
west australia hedland
```

I want to check if there are similar names and get them. So the output should be like:

```
id  x                     name
1   eu continent hamburg hamburg
2   asia singapore       singapore
3   austrlia hedland     hedland
```

How could I do that? I was looking for some solutions and use `str.contains` but the problem was that I need to check through the whole string in both df.

Comment: Can you try using `fuzzywuzzy` library. - This will help in achieving to find similar names between the two DataFrames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try finding similarity between words as below

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrames
data1 = {'id': [1, 2, 3],
         'x': ['eu continent hamburg', 'asia singapore', 'australia hedland']}
data2 = {'name': ['germany hamburg', 'singapore china', 'west australia hedland']}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

def find_best_match(name):
    best_match = None
    best_similarity = 0

    for df2_name in df_2['name']:
        words1 = set(name.split())
        words2 = set(df2_name.split())
        common_words = words1.intersection(words2)
        similarity = len(common_words) / len(words1) 

        if similarity > best_similarity:
            best_similarity = similarity
            best_match = ' '.join(common_words)

    return best_match

df_1['name'] = df_1['x'].apply(find_best_match)


result_df = df_1[['id', 'x', 'name']]
result_df = result_df.rename(columns={'name': 'matched_name'})

print(result_df)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, it looks interesting but I get an error that 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: you can add a check for None before split. `if df2_name is not None:` -  This would help for None values to skip

Comment: I added this condition before line with words1 and made indentation but it didn't help. I will be extremely grateful if you could update your code with this condition

Comment: It works! Thanks. I just removed None values from DF

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution :

```
from itertools import product

matches = [
    next(set(t1).intersection(t2).pop() if set(t1).intersection(t2)
         else None for t1, t2 in product([x], [n])) for (x, n) in zip(
        df1["x"].str.split("\s+"), df2["name"].str.split("\s+")
    )
]

df1["name"] = matches # to assign a new column to `df1`

out = df1.assign(name= matches) # to make a new DataFrame
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   id                     x       name
0   1  eu continent hamburg    hamburg
1   2        asia singapore  singapore
2   3      austrlia hedland    hedland
```